# How to write a function with many variables to represent the following in Show

Tags: webmathematica

How can I write a function with many variables to represent the following in `Show` and get figures?

[image]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code instead of picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I assume you want to plot the values of f and g for fixed z as a function of x and y in one single plot. This can be done e.g. by:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^3;
g[x_, y_, z_] = (x^2 - y^2) z^3;
ff[z_] := 
 Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green]
gg[z_] := Plot3D[g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
Manipulate[Show[ff[z], gg[z]], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) is generally not needed when combining the same type of plots (e.g., both [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)).

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 - z^3;
g[x_, y_, z_] = (x^2 - y^2) z^3;

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  {f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z]},
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y}),
  PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {f, g})],
 {{z, 0.8}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]